# $f(z) = z^3$ then $f(B(x,\delta)) = B(y,\epsilon)$?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z) = z^3$

Let $x\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\delta > 0$

Is true that $f(B(x,\delta)) = B(y,\epsilon)$ for some $y\in \mathbb{C}$ and some $\epsilon > 0$ ?

Where $B(x,\delta) = $ { $a\in\mathbb{C} : |a-x|<\delta$ }

Comment: Not in general. An exception is the case $x=0$.